# Which degree sequences $d_1,...,d_n$ are planar-graphical?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

- Which degree sequences are planar-graphical, that means for which degree sequences
  $$d_1,...,d_n$$ $$d_1\le...\le d_n$$ exists a PLANAR graph that has this degree sequence ?

  I found some links in the internet, but I did not find a concrete classification.
  I know Euler's polyeder formula and that at least one vertex must have degree less
  than $6$ and some similar restrictions, but I would like to have some more powerful
  conditions.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/q/119887/37212, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/145679/755

Answer (score 0):

There is no complete classification of the degree sequences of planar graphs as of today. However, I do have an example for you of an infinite number of similar degree sequences that always contain a planar graph:

$ (N,N,N,N,4,4,4,4,...) $, where $ N > 4 $ and the number of $ 4's $ in the sequence is equal to $ (N-2)^2 $.

Comment: This seems like a very trivial result in this direction. Maybe a bit more interesting is that an $r$-regular planar graph on $n$ vertices always exists provided (1) $rn$ is even, the necessary condition for regular graphs (2) $\frac{rn}{2} \le 3n-6$, Euler's condition for planar graphs, and (3) $(r,n)$ is not $(4,7)$ or $(5,14)$. ([source, I think](https://www.jstor.org/stable/3611937))

Comment: @MishaLavrov What makes it so trivial?

Comment: The fact that it's only about one very specific family of degree sequences.

Comment: Just because it is specific does not mean it's trivial.